# Synchronisation on java.io.File Object

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, synchronization

Is it good to use synchronised on `java.io.File` Object. When you want to alternatively read and write that File Object using two threads: one for reading and one for writing.

```
public class PrintChar {
    File fileObj;
    public void read() {

    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            readFile();
            notifyAll();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " throws Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void write(String temp) {

    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            writeFile(temp);
            notifyAll();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " throws Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setFileObj(File fileObj) {
    this.fileObj = fileObj;
}

public void readFile() {
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeFile(String temp) {
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileObj, true));
        bw.write(temp);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    final PrintChar p = new PrintChar();
    p.setFileObj(new File("C:\\sunny.txt"));

    Thread readingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            p.read();
        }
    });
    Thread writingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            p.write("hello");
        }
    });

    Thread Randomizer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " throws Exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });

    readingThread.start();
    writingThread.start();
    Randomizer.start();
}
```

}

In the code above I have used Synchronised(this), Can i use Synchronise(fileObj)??

**One More solution I have got from one of my professors is to encapsulate the read and write in objects and push them in a fifo after every operation, if anybody elaborate on this**

Comment: Please edit your question to give us some more details. Show some code sample?  How are you reading or writing the file?

Comment: Your professor is suggesting that you avoid the problem by only executing one I/O operation at a time, on a special-purpose I/O thread which gets work from a FIFO queue. That still won't work if you use multiple objects to reference the same underlying physical file, but it does obviate the need for locking assuming the rest of the program is correct. You also need to still be careful (just as you would without the FIFO) about managing the order of I/O operations on the physical file. If you have a thread doing read at offset 0 and another writing at offset 0, which file I/O happens first?

Comment: @Steve I want to Read first and then write. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Now that you have added your code, you *can* lock on `fileObj` but only if it is not changed.  I would move it to the constructor and make it `final` to make sure that someone doesn't call `setFileObj` inappropriately.  Either that or throw an exception if `this.fileObj` is not `null`.

Couple other comments:

- Don't use `notifyAll()` unless you really need to notify multiple threads.
- If you catch `InterruptedException`, I'd quit the thread instead of looping.  Always make good decisions around catching `InterruptedException` and *don't* just print and loop.
- Your `in.close();` should be in a `finally` block.

---

You can lock on any object you want as long as both threads are locking on the same constant object.  It is typical to use a `private final` object for example:

```
  private final File sharedFile = new File(...);

  // reader
  synchronized (sharedFile) {
       // read from file
  }
  ...

  // writer
  synchronized (sharedFile) {
       // write to file
  }
```

What you *can't* do is lock on two different `File` objects, even if they both point to the same file.  The following will *not* work for example:

```
  private static final String SHARED_FILE_NAME = "/tmp/some-file";

  // reader
  File readFile = new File(SHARED_FILE_NAME);
  synchronized (readFile) {
      ...
  }

  // writer
  File writeFile = new File(SHARED_FILE_NAME);
  synchronized (writeFile) {
      ...
  }
```

Also, just because you are locking on the same `File` object does not mean that the reading and writing code will work between the threads.  You will need to make sure that in the writer that all updates are flushed in the synchronized block.  In the reader you probably do not want to use buffered streams otherwise you will have stale data.

Comment: Thanks for the review comments. Any comments on the bold line that I have added

Comment: [Why do you recommend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3186336/1103872) `notify` against `notifyAll`? The latter cannot possibly hurt if there's only one thread in the wait set, but the former can cause all kinds of strange bugs if there are multiple threads.

Comment: @Marko A lot of multithreading code makes use of `notifyAll()` when most should be using `notify()` -- waking up only one thread.  In my experience, rarely do you want to start all threads running.  More typical is you want to signal another consumer of a queue -- like in this example.  It just seems to be to be a sloppy pattern.

Comment: But if there are several consumers, there's no guarantee of fairness -- and if there's only one, then both methods are the same. You seem to have more first-hand experience with this and I'm curious :)

Comment: @Marko If there are several consumers then most likely the first one in the wait queue will be awoken.  Awakening all of the consumers is not going to help because the first one awoken is usually the first one in the wait queue for the lock and the first to consume the item.  I just don't see the point in causing all of the threads to wake up so all but one can go back to sleep.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3186336/1103872) explains very precisely how using `notify` can lead to deadlocks in a multiple producers-multiple consumers scenario. Using `notify` seems like a very dangerous blanket advice.

Comment: Couldn't have shown a better _bad_ example.  That example synchronized on `this` which is also not recommended.  But the issue here is that they are using one lock for both readers and writers.  If you used a read lock and another object as the write lock then the deadlock would never happen and your system would be much more efficient.  Typical bad pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In general, locking across I/O is not a great idea.  It's better to construct your program such that you guarantee by design that usually a given section of the file is not being concurrently written and read, and only lock if you absolutely must mediate between reads and writes of a given piece of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually not. There are much better ways: Use a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

This class already offers the "lock for reading/writing" metaphor. It also correctly handles the case that many threads can read at the same time but only one thread can write.

As other people already mentioned, locking will only work if all threads use the same `File` instance.

Make sure you flush the output buffers after each write; this will cost some performance but otherwise, you'll get stale reads (read thread won't find data that you expect to be there).

If you want to simplify the code, add a third thread which accepts commands from the other two. The commands are `READ` and `WRITE`. Put the commands in a queue and let the 3rd thread wait for entries in the queue. Each command should have a callback method (like `success()`) which the 3rd thread will call when the command has been executed.

This way, you don't need any locking at all. The code for each thread will be much more simple and easy to test.

**[EDIT]** Answer based on your code: It would work in your case because everyone uses the same instance of `fileObj` but it would mix several things into one field. People reading your code would expect the file object to be just the path to the file to read. So the solution would violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

If you'd argue that it would save memory, then I'd reply with "[premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize)".

Try to find a solution which clearly communicates your intent. "Clever" coding is good for your ego but that's about the only positive thing that one can say about it (and it's not good for your ego to learn what people will say about you after they see your "clever" code for the first time...) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have modified something in my Question. Would you please check I think it is similar to what you are trying to say. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Queueing off read/write objects to one thread that then performs the operation is a valid approach to something, but I'm not sure what.

Wha it would not do, for example, is to enforce read/write/read/write order as you specified in your earlier question.  There is nothing to stop the read thread queueing up 100 read requests.

That could be prevented by making the thread that submits an object wait on it until it is signaled by the read/write thread, but this seems a very complex way of just enforcing read/write order, (assuming that's what you still want).

I'm getting to the state now where I'm not sure what it is you need/want.