# Java thread wait() notify() in one method

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

```
public class Signal2NoiseRatio
{
    public ImagePlus SingleSNR(ImagePlus imagePlus) throws InterruptedException
    {

        new Thread()
        { 
          @Override public void run() 
          { 
              for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
              { 
                  System.out.println("in queue"+i);
              }

              synchronized( this ) 
              { 
                  this.notify(); 
              }
            } 
        }.start();


        synchronized (this) 
        {
        this.wait();
        }


        return imagePlusToProcess;
    }
}
```

`notify()` does not reach `wait()`.

what's wrong here?

It is essential for me that both synchonized methods in this one method are implemented.

the main thread perform a frame which presents an image in it. Is it possible that the `wait()` method leads the frame to a white window?

Comment: ``this.notify`` points to the new Thread

Comment: `synchronized(Signal2NoiseRatio.this)`

Comment: Its also safer to use notifyAll instead of notify. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again

Comment: *in one method* there are 2 methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the `SingleSNR` method and `this` in the overridden `run` method are not the same object (inside `run`, `this` refers to the anonymous subclass of `Thread`).  You need to make sure you are notifying the same object you `wait` for, which is available as `Signal2NoiseRatio.this`:

```
      @Override public void run() 
      { 
          for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
          { 
              System.out.println("in queue"+i);
          }

          synchronized( Signal2NoiseRatio.this ) 
          { 
              Signal2NoiseRatio.this.notify(); 
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

two "this"s are not the same, one is Signal2NoiseRatio, one is the Thread