# Why do I get an infinite while loop even if I modify the lock variable?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class GuardedBlock {

    private boolean guard = false;

    private static void threadMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuardedBlock guardedBlock = new GuardedBlock();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    guardedBlock.guard = true;
                    threadMessage("Set guard=true");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadMessage("Start waiting");
                while (!guardedBlock.guard) {
                    //threadMessage("Still waiting...");
                }
                threadMessage("Finally!");
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

I was learning concurrency through java essentials tutorial. Got to guarded blocks and tried to test it. There is one thing I cannot understand.

While loop is infinite, but if you uncomment threadMessage line everything works fine. Why?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The changes to `guard` will not be visible to other threads if it not volatile.

Comment: When you comment out that line then there is nothing left inside your while loop, and Java is smart enough to ignore the complete while loop. So, its as good as there is no while loop.

Comment: what do you mean by everything works fine. does it print still waiting ? then finally ?

Comment: Does it work if you change `guard` to `volatile guard`? Also a busy-wait loops are bad, I don't recommend you using them. Consider using `wait` and `notify` instead.

Comment: @hagrawal: That can't be true.  If it was, OP would not experience an infinite loop.  Rather, as akhil_mittal is saying, `guard` is not `volatile`.  So its value isn't guaranteed to be synchronized between threads. Adding the `threadMessage` line must be triggering some sort of memory barrier that happens to help in synchronizing the thread's view of the `guard` value.  But that is very unreliable behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer**

You forgot to declare `guard` as a volatile boolean.

---

If you ommit the declaration of your field as `volatile`, you are not telling the JVM that this field can be seen by multiple thread which is the case in your example.

In such cases, the value of `guard` will be read only once and will cause an infinite loop. It will be optimized to something like this (without the print) :

```
if(!guard)
{
    while(true)
    {
    }
}
```

Now why `System.out.println` change this behaviour ? Because the `writes` are synchronized which force the threads to not cache reads.

Here a paste of the code of one of the `println` method of `PrintStream` used by `System.out.println` :

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

and the `write` method :

```
private void write(String s) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(s);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

notice the synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

Jean-Francois's solution is the correct one:  you absolutely must have some sort of synchronization when threads access a shared variable, whether it's via `volatile`, `synchronized`, etc.

I would also add that your `while` loop amounts to what is called [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) - that is, repeatedly testing a condition in a concurrent setting.  The tight loop of the busy waiting in this code may hog the CPU.  At the very least its effects on system resources will be unpredictable.

You may want to explore the [condition variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) approach to dealing with multiple threads being affected by a single shared condition. Java has many higher level tools for this in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) library, but it's good to know the older lower-level API methods, especially since you are working directly with `Thread` instances already.

Every [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) has [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) and [`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) methods. The `Object` represents the condition, or at least the monitor associated with it.  The `wait()` method is called within a `while` loop that tests the condition, and blocks the calling thread until some other thread calls `notifyAll()`.  Then all waiting threads will be awakened, and they will all have compete for the lock and the chance to test the condition again. If the condition just stays true at that point, then all the threads will proceed.

Here's what your code would look like using this approach:

```
public class GuardedBlock {

    private boolean guard = false;

    private static void threadMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GuardedBlock guardedBlock = new GuardedBlock();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    synchronized (guardedBlock) {
                        guardedBlock.guard = true;
                        guardedBlock.notifyAll();
                    }
                    threadMessage("Set guard=true");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadMessage("Start waiting");
                while (!guardedBlock.guard) {
                    synchronized (guardedBlock) {
                        try {
                            guardedBlock.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                threadMessage("Finally!");
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Notice the following:

- Lock must be taken whenever condition is read or written (via
  `synchronized` keyword.)
- `guard` condition is tested inside a `while` loop, but that loop blocks during the `wait()` call. The only reason it is still a `while` loop is to handle situations where there are many threads and the condition changes many times. Then the condition should be re-tested when a thread is awakened, in case another thread changes the condition in the tiny gap between the awakening and the re-taking of the lock.
- Waiting threads are notified when `guard` condition is set to `true` (via `notifyAll()` calls.)
- Program blocks on the `thread2` instance at the
  very end, so that we don't exit the main thread before all threads
  finish (via the [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) call.)

If you look at the `Object` API, you'll see there's also a [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) method. It's simpler to always use `notifyAll()`, but if you want to understand the difference between these two methods, [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your while loop is infinite is that the condition `!guardedBlock.guard` is always true. That means `guardedBlock.guard = true;` set in Thread 1 is not set for Thread 2, and that happens because you are not using the variable guard as `volatile`.

Let me copy the need of using the volatile in java from wikipedia itself:

> In all versions of Java, there is a global ordering on the reads and writes to a volatile variable. This implies that **every thread accessing a volatile field will read its current value before continuing**, instead of (potentially) using a cached value.

Hope that helps.