# Which thread will start running after notify among mulitiple waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm trying to understand how `notify` & `notifyAll` are different.

Lets consider a case in which thread `t1` is using a resource `R`. And now two threads `t2` & `t3` are waiting on the same resource. If `t1` invokes `notify` method on `R`, which one of `t2` & `t3` will start? If `t1` invokes `notifyAll` method on `R`, both `t2` & `t3` will be notified but as they are still competing for same resource only one of them should be able to start. And which one will be able to do so?

Comment: From the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) *"Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. **The choice is arbitrary** and occurs at the discretion of the implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.*"

Comment: You can find your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again

Answer (score 0):

You can't guess which one exactly will start to work. [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) says that it's the arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 0):

Object.notify() will select a random waiting thread and notify that the lock is 
   released and it can go ahead with obtaining the lock for itself. 
   Object.notifyAll() will  notify all the thread which are waiting for the lock 
   of that object and they compete over to obtain the lock.

Initially we may think , then if i set varying priorities to each thread then i 
   can control the sequence. But that not the case , priorities doesn't guarantee 
   that the higher priority threads will run.

But if you really want to control the sequence of thread execution use 
   thread synchronizers.

To test that priorities has little say in the Thread selection :

```
public class NotifyVSNotifyAll {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object resource = new Object();

        Thread a=new Thread(()->{
                                   synchronized (resource) {
                                       System.out.println("A");
                                       try{
                                          Thread.sleep(2000);
                                          resource.notify();
                                      //resource.notifyAll();
                                       }catch(Exception E){}
                                   }  

                                 });
        Thread b=new Thread(()->{
            synchronized (resource) {
               System.out.println("B");
               }  

          });
        Thread c=new Thread(()->{
            synchronized (resource) {
               System.out.println("C");
               }  

          });

        a.setPriority(10);
        b.setPriority(1);
        c.setPriority(10);

        a.start();
        c.start();
        b.start();

    }


}

Hope its clear.
```