# Java: notify vs notify all

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

Having hard time to understand the difference in benefits of using notify over notifyall and vice versa.
Lets say that we have an object L that we want to lock and four threads: A, B, C and D. Now A enters run method and obtains a lock on object L while B, C and D are waiting to be notified.
So what is the difference between notifying these waiting threads individually with notify and notifying all of them at once with notifyall since in both cases we have no control over which thread after A obtains a lock on object L.

Comment: In both cases one thread will wake if one is waiting, but do you want them all to wake?

Comment: i dont mind if one or all wake and go into a runnable state since it has no effect on the outcome and no effect on which thread will be selected to run next

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046/2156877

Comment: the answer made two point the second which is what peter said which really has no effect on the outcome. the second point says use notifyall when u want to select one specific thread to lock the object and wake the rest to do something else. The second point makes no sense because that would be possible if we had the option to decide which specific thread with specific implementation to lock the object. The next thread to lock the object might be from one of the other threads that does something else not related to object resource possession.

Comment: yes this question has been posted before but the answers are really vague and paraphrase what peter lawrey has said.