# java, synchronized in two separate methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create thread safe queue in java. I've come across this example:

```
class ProducerConsumer<T> {
   private static final int BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = 42;
   private List<T> buffer = new LinkedList<>();

   synchronized void produce(T value) throws InterruptedException {
      while (buffer.size() == BUFFER_MAX_SIZE) {
         wait();
      }
      buffer.add(value);
      notify();
   }

   synchronized T consume() throws InterruptedException {
      while (buffer.size() == 0) {
         wait();
      }
      T result = buffer.remove(0);
      notify();
      return result;
   }
}
```

I'm new to java. In my understanding those two 'synchronized' keywords would prevent contention inside each method, but not when both methods are called simultaneously. E.g. thread P calls produce, locks method, thread C calls consume, locks other method, then one tries to extract element from list, another tries to insert element, thread exception arises.

**My question: Is this example broken?**

Or maybe I'm missing something and it's ok.

Comment: If methods are `synchronized`, they synchronize over the `this` object. Thus, it is guaranteed that at one point in time on one object at most one thread is executing either  `produce` or `consume`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locks method"?

Comment: I see, i thought each method has it's own lock, like critical section.

Comment: I don't think your methods are broken though, because `wait()` releases the lock and allows another thread to call either method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JLS, §17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) is quite explicit about the mechanism:

> ...
>
> A `synchronized` method ([§8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as `this` during execution of the body of the method). If the method is `static`, it locks the monitor associated with the `Class` object that represents the class in which the method is defined. If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.
>
> ...

Thus, it is guaranteed that at one point in time on one object at most one thread is executing either  `produce(...)` or `consume()`. It is not possible that, at one point in time, one thread executes `produce(...)` on an object while another thread executes `consume()` on the same object.

The call to `wait()` in `consume()` releases the intrinsic lock and blocks execution. The call to `notify()` in `produce(...)` notifies one `wait()`ing thread (if any), so it can fight for the lock as soon as the lock is released by the current owner. Notice that a call to `notify()` does not release the intrinsic lock. It just wakes up a `wait()`ing thread. This can be made observable with the following code snippet:

```
class Ideone {
  private static final Object lock = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printWithThreadNamePrefix("Start");
    Thread waiter = new Thread(Ideone::waiter);
    waiter.start();

    // Give waiter some time to a) start and b) acquire the intrinsic lock
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    final Thread notifier = new Thread(Ideone::notifier);
    notifier.start();

    while (true) {
      try {
        waiter.join();
        break;
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }

    printWithThreadNamePrefix("End");
  }

  private static void waiter() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      printWithThreadNamePrefix("Waiting...");
      while (true) {
        try {
          lock.wait();
          break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
      printWithThreadNamePrefix("... done waiting");
    }
  }

  private static void printWithThreadNamePrefix(String msg) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
        "%s: %s",
        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
        msg));
  }

  private static void notifier() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      printWithThreadNamePrefix("notifying");
      lock.notify();
      while (true) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sAsGMU)

The program will never terminate. Although thread `two` calls `notify()`, it then enters an endless loop, never actually releasing the intrinsic lock. Thus, `one` never has a chance to acquire the intrinsic lock, and the program "hangs" (it is neither a deadlock, nor a livelock, it simply cannot proceed).

The things I recommend to change are:

- declare `private List<T> buffer` additionally as `final`
- call `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()` in order to wake all waiting threads (they will still execute sequentially, for details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again) by [Sergey Mikhanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894/sergey-mikhanov) and its answers)